# Hindi speech to text for android

Tags: android, speech-recognition

Is there any free API or any other method to convert continues Hindi speech to Hindi text in android. Please note that the speech can be as long as 1 minute. Online or offline doesn't matter. Also please state the method to implement it in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Speech to Text Apis available on android which also supports hindi. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/package-summary.html

Comment: Thanks. But for hindi isn't it is required to change language setting to hindi in device? Moreover it stops to listen once you pause for a moment, without listening more.